# Removing view from its superview

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have added a few buttons to self.view. When the user clicks on one button, i will load another view (subView). My code where i am loading the subView is shown below

```
subView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,self.scrollView.contentSize.width, self.scrollView.contentSize.height)];
subView.tag=1;
// and then i add various other components to it

[self.view addSubview:subView]; // and finally add it to the view
```

When the user touches this view, i detect it and remove the view (i have already done the detection part).

This is how i am removing the view

```
UIView *v = [self.subView viewWithTag:1];
    v.hidden = YES;
    [v endEditing:YES];
 [v removeFromSuperview];
```

The view dissapears, but i can't click on the buttons or anything that was on the self.view. When i hold the mouse cursor on a button for awhile i could click it otherwise i can't. How can i solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that you do

```
[self.subView viewWithTag:1];
```

but the view you want to remove is "owned" by self.view so it should be

```
[self.view viewWithTag:1];
```

But if you have a reference to subView, why search it again? Why not immediately:

```
self.subView.hidden = YES;
[self.subView endEditing:YES];
[self.subView removeFromSuperview];
```

Btw you might want to look into your memory management, I see you alloc your subView but I don't see it being released, when the view is removed again. Maybe you do and you just don't show the code, in that case forget my comment.

Comment: I am using ARC. so need not remove

Answer (score 3):

Try removing the subview like this:

```
for (UIView *subView in self.view.subviews) {
    if (subView.tag == (int)yourSubViewTag) {

        [subView removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `yourSubViewTag` ? what should come there ?

Comment: the tag you want to compare to.. "1", "2", or "152"  `int yourSubViewTag = 1;  subView.tag=yourSubViewTag;`

Comment: but has Vicent said, if you have a reference (property) you can do it immediately: `[subView removeFromSuperview];` don't need to search for it.

Answer (score 2):

Should this line:

```
UIView *v = [self.subView viewWithTag:1];
```

really be:

```
UIView *v = [self.view viewWithTag:1];
```

?