# Removing subView from SuperView

Tags: iphone, objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Removing view from its superview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8853544/removing-view-from-its-superview)

I have added a few buttons to self.view. When the user clicks on one button, i will load another view (subView). My code where i am loading the subView is shown below

```
subView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,280, 460)];
subView.tag=1;
// and then i add various other components to it

[self.view addSubview:subView]; // and finally add it to the view
```

When the user touches this view, i detect it and remove the view (i have already done the detection part).

This is how i am removing the view

```
UIView *v = [self.subView viewWithTag:1];
    v.hidden = YES;
    [v endEditing:YES];
 [v removeFromSuperview];
```

The view dissapears, but i can't click on the buttons or anything that was on the self.view. When i hold the mouse cursor on a button for awhile i could click it otherwise i can't. How can i solve this ?